# Java save String to Excel file as a URL

Tags: java, excel, url, apache-poi

Hi i'm trying to save a string (http://www.google.com) to a my Excel file in a Hyperlink format but the string is saved as plain text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
  HSSFHyperlink link = createHelper.createHyperlink(HSSFHyperlink.LINK_URL);
  link.setAddress(Result);
  Cell.setHyperlink(link);
```

Comment: It's better to use interface instead of implementation as you shouldn't care what type of workbook you are using: `Hyperlink link = createHelper.createHyperlink(Hyperlink.LINK_URL);`